# Swift Perfect does not load image or css

Tags: swift, perfect

I am new to [perfect](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect), and the thing is, it does not load css or image for some reason. I have put them all in the same directory:

- webroot:

  - index.html
  - styles.css
  - pic.jpg

And the code is just:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="styles.css">
<img src='/pic.jpg' align="left" width="150" height="150">
```

But, they are not loaded no matter what I try. So can someone answer me this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that you've already set the static route properly:

```
"routes":[
    ["method":"get", "uri":"/**",  
     "handler":PerfectHTTPServer.HTTPHandler.staticFiles,
     "documentRoot":"./webroot"]
]
```

Then try "swift build" and run the app in a Terminal

If using Xcode, please choose "Edit Scheme" from the Xcode "run" and set the option "Working Directory" to "$(PROJECT_DIR)".